# How to add Image background in signaturepad Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, signaturepad

I want to make signature pad with fix background Image, and save the image to the public folder in laravel.

i use this code to make signaturepad : https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-signature-pad-example-tutorialexample.html

[image: I want to make like this]

[image: I want to add background image in this signaturepad]

Comment: At least you need to show what you have attempted (show your OWN code which you have attempted for implementing this function)

Answer (score 0):

so this is my code, is possible add fix image background in the signaturepad ?

routes/web.php

```
<?php
  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  
use App\Http\Controllers\SignaturePadController;
  
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
  
Route::get('signaturepad', [SignaturePadController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('signaturepad', [SignaturePadController::class, 'upload'])->name('signaturepad.upload')
```

app/Http/Controllers/SignaturePadController.php

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  
class SignaturePadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('signaturePad');
    }
  
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $folderPath = public_path('upload/');
        
        $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->signed);
              
        $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
           
        $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
           
        $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
           
        $file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.'.$image_type;
        file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
        return back()->with('success', 'success Full upload signature');
    }
}
```

resources/view/signaturePad.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel Signature Pad Tutorial Example - ItSolutionStuff.com </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.signature.js"></script>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.signature.css">
  
    <style>
        .kbw-signature { width: 100%; height: 200px;}
        #sig canvas{
            width: 100% !important;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
  
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-5">
           <div class="card">
               <div class="card-header">
                   <h5>Laravel Signature Pad Tutorial Example - ItSolutionStuff.com </h5>
               </div>
               <div class="card-body">
                    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success  alert-dismissible">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>  
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('signaturepad.upload') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="" for="">Signature:</label>
                            <br/>
                            <div id="sig" ></div>
                            <br/>
                            <button id="clear" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Clear Signature</button>
                            <textarea id="signature64" name="signed" style="display: none"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    </form>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sig = $('#sig').signature({syncField: '#signature64', syncFormat: 'PNG'});
    $('#clear').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sig.signature('clear');
        $("#signature64").val('');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```